# In function repeat an action for each entered parameter

Tags: powershell

My main script run once gci on a specified drive via -path parameter , then it does multiple different tables from this output. Here below is a part of my script which does a specific table from an directory specified via -folder parameter, for example :

```
my-globalfunction -path d:\ -folder d:\folder
```

It work fine, but only for one entered folder path, the goal of this script is that user can enter multiple folders path and get a tables for each entered -folder parameter value, like this :

Comment: `.StartsWith` works with strings. Not arrays. Your logic here would need to change: `.StartsWith($folder`. Regex would help with that easy.

Comment: My answer looks really weird when you remove all the code from your question. How would you determine the variable name for each folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This clause in your `Where-Object` would be the issue:

```
$_.FullName.StartsWith($folder, [System.StringComparison]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

The array of folders passed are most likely being cast as one long string which would never match. I had a regex solution posted but remembered a simpler way after looking at what your logic was trying to do.

## Simpler Way

Even easier way is to put this information right into `Get-ChildItem` since it accepts string arrays for `-Path`. This way I don't think you even need to have 2 parameters since you never again use the results from `$fol` anyway. Based on the assumption that you were looking for all subfolders of `$folder`

```
$gdfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -Force | Where-Object{$_.psiscontainer}
```

That would return all subfolders of the paths provided. If you have PowerShell 3.0 or higher this would even be easier.

```
$gdfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -Force -Directory
```

**Update from comments**

The code you have displayed is incomplete which is what lead me to the solution that you see above. If you do use the variable `$fol` somewhere else that you do not show lets go back to my earlier regex solution which would work better in place with what you already have.

```
$regex = "^($(($folder | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|")).+"
....
$gdfolders = $fol | Where-Object{($_.Attributes -eq "Directory") -and ($_.FullName -match $regex)}
```

What this will do is build a regex compare string with what I will assume is the logic of locate folders that begin with either of paths passed.

Using your example input of `"d:\folder1", "d:\folder2"` the variable `$regex` would work out to `^(d:\\folder1|d:\\folder2)`. The proper characters, like `\`, are escaped automatically by the static method `[regex]::Escape` which is applied to each element. We then use `-join` to place a pipe which, in this regex capture group means match whats on the left *OR* on the right. For completeness sake we state that the match has to occur at the beginning of the path with the caret `^` although this is most likely redundant. It would match paths that start with either "d:\folder1" or "d:\folder2". At the end of the regex string we have .+ which means match 1 to more characters. This should ensure we dont match the actual folder "d:\folder1" but meerly its children

**Side Note**

The quotes in the line with `’Size (MB)’` are not the proper ones which are `'`. If you have issues around that code consider changing the quotes.

Comment: Hi Matt thank you for answer. But as i said the output or f my gci command is used for building different tables ( table with files report, folder report...) so it is not possible add ?{$_.psiscontainer} to this command.

Comment: @Cavalli But that is what you did with `$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"`?

Comment: @Cavalli Is `$gdfolders` not supposed to contain all the subfolders of `[string[]]$folder`?

Comment: i can not add $_.Attributes -eq "Directory" in my main gci, if i do that I could not use my $fol output for my other tables where i need to get info from files...

Comment: Matt thank you very much for your help, i finally used this solution is also yours but from another topic : $gdfolders = $folder | % { $regexPath = [regex]::Escape($_)
    $fol | ? {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory" -and $_.FullName -match "^$regexPath"}
    }.

Comment: Now i have to make a separate table for each entered $folder value, because the actual result is a table with all directory in.